# Weird box plot result when trying to create a box plot in ggplot2 using linearized data

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I have an interactions matrix that looks like this:

```
                               chr10.117800000 chr10.117801000 chr10.117802000 chr10.117803000 chr10.117804000 chr10.117805000 chr10.117806000
            chr10.117800000     0.006484824     0.006451925     0.006422584     0.006386328     0.006292793     0.006277799     0.006231732
            chr10.117801000     0.006451925     0.006435975     0.006415112     0.006378994     0.006285668     0.006272825     0.006226796
            chr10.117802000     0.006422584     0.006415112     0.006406884     0.006370748     0.006277475     0.006264644     0.006222890
            chr10.117803000     0.006386328     0.006378994     0.006370748     0.006346183     0.006307680     0.006294757     0.006254941
            chr10.117804000     0.006292793     0.006285668     0.006277475     0.006307680     0.006324919     0.006311969     0.006276300
            chr10.117805000     0.006277799     0.006272825     0.006264644     0.006294757     0.006311969     0.006303327     0.006269839
            chr10.117806000     0.006231732     0.006226796     0.006222890     0.006254941     0.006276300     0.006269839     0.006244967
            chr10.117807000     0.006242481     0.006235449     0.006231538     0.006265652     0.006287100     0.006282769     0.006257918
            chr10.117808000     0.006140677     0.006133760     0.006129913     0.006161364     0.006188786     0.006186627     0.006166320
            chr10.117809000     0.006098614     0.006091771     0.006087950     0.006119074     0.006146385     0.006146359     0.006130442
```

I am trying to linearize and label it to prep it for ggplot2, which I have accomplished using this code:

```
 data <- as.vector(data)
 data <- cbind(Counts = data, Genotype = "KO")
```

However, whenever I take my data and plot it using ggplot2 with this command:

```
 blah <- ggplot(data =test, aes(x = Genotype, y = Counts)) + geom_boxplot()
```

It gives me a weird looking box plot that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to add scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.002)), but each time that I do that I get an error that I'm trying to add discrete values to a continuous scale. Does anyone know what's going on, or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Please dput your data.

Comment: You have probably an issue with the format of your y value. Try to convert it in a numerical format (`as.numeric`)

Comment: how would you want to make the boxplot? Every column will be one group?

Comment: Hey everyone, dc37 got it, I needed to convert to numeric. However, it's worth noting that when converting a factor to a numeric you cannot simply use as.numeric(), you must specify as.numeric(levels(data))[data]